# Framework for visualization of simulation

Tags: java, python, user-interface, simulation

I'm currently working on a task, a simulation of robots moving in a two-dimensional plane, to be more specific. I've got to **visualize** their movement over time, but I'm not quite sure which framework to use.

Can anyone recommend me one? Preferably *Python* or *Java*.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: This is a shopping list question - closing as not constructive.

Comment: Here's a basic Java Swing [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513), _sans_ framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python you can use [matplot](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and the gallery gives you plenty of choice. You might want to expand on what you want you want to visualise.

**EDIT**

Well for complex stuff there's 
[processing](http://processing.org) and perhaps you want to produce something like this ?
[flocking](http://processing.org/learning/topics/flocking.html)

Another tool is http://nodebox.net/ which uses Python to create interesting graphs infographics.

Comment: I thought about using that, but I'm not sure whether it's flexible enough because I have more than 100 moving robots and I want to have different simulation speeds...

Comment: I suspected as much :D  - How about http://processing.org/ ? - perhaps change you Q to point to an example of the sort of thing you want to produce.

Comment: Well, basically it's about visualizing a method of making a certain number of anonymous robots with limited visibility gather in a single point, so that you can see how they move.

Comment: That flocking example at processing would seem suitable?

Comment: @MustafaIsik all of this information needs to go into your original post.  It sounds like you have done a lot of thought and research and know some options but understand the limits of each.  This can make for a good specific question if it includes this information and research, but as it stands I voted to close your question as just asking for a list of visualization tool recommendations.

Comment: I'll try with Slick2D in Java. Thank you for your help!