# getting rotation angle from moving object's speed x,y?

Tags: java, flash, math, actionscript, formula

What is the formula used to determining moving object's rotation angle from its velocity or vector direction of travel?

For example, if an airplane is moving toward position (x1,y1) = (200, 100) from  position (x0, y0) = (0,0), which angle would the plane be facing?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184).  It basically calculates the direction an object must have in order to follow a given path.

Comment: Velocity is how fast the speed increases or decreases, it doesn't say of the curve the object is taking. For example the plane could go in a straight line, therefore the angle would be 0, but the plane could go in a wide curve that would make the angle be 90...

Comment: Depends what you mean by "angle of rotation". If you mean the angle made by the ray emanating from (0,0) along the x-axis and the ray emanating from (0,0) and passing through (200,100), then simple trigonometry can tell you. If you mean something else, I'm afraid you'll need to say what that is before your question is answerable.

Comment: this would be SAS - Side Angle Side trig

Comment: Thanks for the replies. lol I think I really suck at math. What I meant was simply getting angle(in 0-360degrees) from an object that moves by, for example, x:2 y:3 every second. I remember the formula was pretty simple but dont remember exactly what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the angle between two points, you plug the points into this code:

```
var _radians:Number = Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1);
```

"_radians" is the angle in radians.

To rotate a DisplayObject, you can use its rotation property, after converting the angle into degrees.

```
var _degrees:Number = _radians * ( 180 / Math.PI );
_displayObject.rotation = _degrees;
```

You may need to add a contant to the rotation to line up with your art.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the formula I was looking for. Thanks both for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

By rotation angle you apparently mean azimuth.  The function `Math.atan2(dy, dx)` is the right approach.  In your example with `p1 = (x1, y1) = (200,100)` and `p0 = (x0, y0) = (0,0)`, you'd want `Math.atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0)`.  This will return the angle in radians. To convert to degrees, multiply by `180 / Math.PI`.

Comment: +1. Assuming you're working in Flash from the question tags, one thing to bear in mind is that `Math.atan2` returns an angle relative to negative x, but `DisplayObject.rotation` is relative to negative y.