# How do you use a Timer to repaint after changes?

Tags: java, user-interface, timer, paint

I currently have a GUI program that repaints, however it does not have a `Timer` implemented so it is repainting at every clock from the CPU (which is taking my CPU up to 65% usage). I've seen mention that a `Timer` can solve this problem by scheduling tasks to run after however many ticks you choose. However, I'm not sure how to implement it into my program. My program currently looks similar to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create new Jframe
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.add(new Game());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while (1 == 1)
    {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

The paint method handles various parts of the game such as movement. For example, if a forward button is clicked, the GUI will repaint with the player moved up by one. When I searched examples of a `Timer`, it was used in the `run()` method which I do not have in my program. Does the `Timer` get implemented into the body of the class (e.g. inside the `paintComponent()` method) and then ran inside `main()`?

I tried using something such as this:

```
paintComponent()
{
    // everything that it does
    Timer updater = new Timer(1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create new Jframe
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.add(new Game());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while (1 == 1)
    {
        new Timer(1);
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as I believe that timers need to be ran.

Comment: Well, to start with, don't put it the `paintComponent` method!

Comment: You may be looking for `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: What frame work?  Swing/AWT/GWT/Android/JavaFX?  Are you using a `BufferedStrategy` or just painting to the `Graphics` context via one of the paint methods?

Comment: Think about this, 60fps is an average delay of 16 milliseconds...

Comment: `Game()` is just a `JPanel` that is painting to a `Graphics` context.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818753/java-animations/18818797#18818797) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184)