# Tools for building a GUI for the given co-ordinates

Tags: java, swing, japplet

Hi I am doing a project for my university and i am developing a robot which could use ACO(Ant Colony Optimization) for finding a shortest route out of the maze.I am using a finch robot and I am trying to build a GUI for the path travelled by the robot. I am recording a path in an arrayList in a form of x-y co-ordinates and trying to display the path recorded in some form of display(like a moving dot in specified co-ordinate). Since I am a beginner in using graphics or visuals in java i am having trouble creating a display.Can you suggest what tool could i use to track the path of the robot?Currently I am programming in Java in Eclipse.Thank in advance.

Comment: Consider the MVC pattern examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) and this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513).

Comment: If you don't need any mouth-opening visual effects, you could just draw points and lines on a 2D surface. This is pretty simple, have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html

Comment: thanks...i think java 2D will help.