# Cursor Input on Libgdx is returned "incorrectly"

Tags: java, swing, input, graphics, libgdx

I'm currently making my own level creator(tile map) for a project I'm going to be working on soon. It's all going fine, except I ran into a problem when I added an option to zoom in and out. I have a class that is handling all the input and rendering currently, as I just am getting started.

```
LevelEditorController extends InputAdapter implements ApplicationListener
```

As you can see, this class extends InputAdapter and implements ApplicationListener.

```
cameraHelper = new CameraHelper();
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH,
        Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
camera.position.set(0f, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT / 2, 1f);
camera.update();
cameraHelper.setPosition(camera.position.x, camera.position.y,
                camera.position.z);
```

camera is an OrthographicCamera. cameraHelper is a helper class I made. I set the position for the camera here. cameraHelper.setPosition(...) simply sets a Vertice3 in my CameraHelper class.

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Above, in the overridden render method, I set the project matrix of my batch and shapeRenderer.

All of this I believe works, as everything is displayed correctly, and only the cursor location is off.

```
@Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
            for (int i = 0; i < boundingBoxes.size; i++) {
                if (boundingBoxes.get(i).toRectangle()
                        .contains(x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y)
                        && !boundingBoxes.get(i).isActive()) {
                    boundingBoxes.get(i).setRenderFull(true);
                } else {
                    boundingBoxes.get(i).setRenderFull(false);
                }
            }
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(0.53f, 0.62f, 0.32f, 1f);
            shapeRenderer.circle(x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y, 20);
            shapeRenderer.end();
            return false;
        }
```

Here's where my issue is. In the above method, I simply check if the cursor location intersects one of the grid squares. If it does, I make the grid square "renderFull", which renders a full(filled in) rectangle of a different color. Also in this method, I draw a circle of where the current cursor pointer is. And this is where my problem is. When I run my program, the circle is not where my cursor is. I spent about an hour debugging and trying to come up with some algorithm based on the zoom to correctly align it, but to no avail. Is there a way to get the correct position of my cursor no matter my zoom? And also, this may be an issue I run into, my "world" size(the grid) is about 10000 pixels long. Will the cursor position also move along with this, or will it stay within the actual program's/Jframe's size? And if so, any way I can fix this(I suppose it would be as simple as adding on the camera's position to the cursors position, but just wanted to check just in case. :D)
Here are some pictures so you can better understand what the issue is.
[image: Zoom at 1]

[image: Zoom at... further than 1]
[image: Zoom at 10]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: [`CabPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513) may offer some insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to unproject the input points into the coordinate system used by your camera.

`touchMoved(int x, int y)` will simply contain the pixel positions on the screen. By using `camera.unproject(Vector3 window)` you will get these touch coordinates in your world/scene coordinates.

This way, the touch positions should match. Hope it helps... :)

Comment: Thanks! I should've known. I just did the same thing except in 3d space. My laptop, unfortunately, received water damage. Looks like the hard drive was fried. 

Comment: Then I'd definitely recommend backing the projects up on Github, Bitbucket or on your own server for future projects... ;) Glad I could help...

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely be keeping backups from now on.  I lost all of my projects, but luckily the only important one had been zipped and uploaded.  I will, however, miss all my notes and personal files I had. I'm going to take this opportunity and start with a new slate.:)