# Swing 2D game low performance

Tags: java, performance, swing, awt, repaint

I am making a clone of Flappy Bird. I was doing just fine performance-wise: 60 fps. This was when it had 1 pillar/obstacle only. As soon as I added 3 of them my fps dropped to 30 and below. Then game is unplayable now. I get that this has something to do with doing `repaint()` all the time.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Lazar on 25/05/15.
 */
public class Environment extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

    public static final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(800,600);
    BufferedImage img;
    BufferedImage ptica1;
    BufferedImage ptica2;
    double skokbrojac = 0; 
    int brzina = 4; // speed // MUST Background % brzina = 0
    int dx;
    int dx2;
    int pad = 0; //drop
    Timer timer;
    boolean parno;
    boolean skok = false;

    //Stubovi // Pillars
    Stub stub1 = new Stub();
    Stub stub2 = new Stub();
    Stub stub3 = new Stub();
    ArrayList<Stub>stubovi = new ArrayList<Stub>();
    int razmakStub; // Space between pillars

    public Environment() {
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        img = Util.openImage("pozadina.png");
        ptica1 = Util.openImage("ptica1.png");
        ptica2 = Util.openImage("ptica2.png");

        stubovi.add(stub1);
        stubovi.add(stub2);
        stubovi.add(stub3);

        dx = img.getWidth()/2;
        timer = new Timer(1000/60,this); 
        timer.start();

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e);
                skok = true;  // start jump
                skokbrojac = 0; //jump frame counter
            }
        });

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        if(dx == img.getWidth()){ //image horizontal scroll
            dx2 = 0;
        }
        if(dx2 == img.getWidth()/2){ //image horizontal scroll
            dx = dimension.width;
        }
        g2d.drawImage(img,getWidth() - dx, 0, null); //draw background
        if(dx >= img.getWidth()){
            g2d.drawImage(img,getWidth() - dx2, 0, null);
        }
        if(parno){
            g2d.drawImage(ptica1,dimension.width/2, 290 + pad, null); //draw bird
        }
        else{
            g2d.drawImage(ptica2,dimension.width/2, 290 + pad, null); //draw bird
        }
        stub1.postoji = true; //pillar1 exists?
        if(razmakStub > 240){
            stub2.postoji = true;
        }
        if(razmakStub > 480){ //pillar1 exists?
            stub3.postoji = true;
        }
        for(Stub i : stubovi){ //draw pillars if they exist
            if(i.postoji)
                i.crtaj(g2d);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dx = dx + brzina; 
        dx2 = dx2 + brzina;

        if(skokbrojac > 5) // jump frame lenght
            skok = false;
        if(skok){
            pad -= 15; // jump height
        }
        else{  
            pad += 8; //rate of the fall
        }
        skokbrojac++;
        parno ^= true; // for different bird images
        if(290 + pad >= 536 || 290 + pad<= 3) //border hit detect
            timer.stop();
        razmakStub += brzina;
        for(Stub i : stubovi){ //reset pillars and make them move
            if(i.postoji){
                if(i.getDx() < -50){
                    i.setDx(800);
                    i.randomDy();
                }
                i.setDx(i.getDx() - brzina);
            }
        }   
        repaint();
    }
}
```

[Complete project source](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b377ebd17bzzn85/Flappy.rar)

Also bear in mind this is really unpolished version so the code is ugly. I am looking for a solution to boost performance.

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by Lazar on 25/05/15.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Frame(new Environment());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Frame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by Lazar on 25/05/15.
 */
public class Frame extends JFrame{

    public Frame(JComponent content){
        setContentPane(content);
        setTitle("Flappy");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Stub/Pillar class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Lazar on 26/05/15.
 */
public class Stub {

    BufferedImage dole;
    BufferedImage gore;
    Random r = new Random();
    int dx = 700;
    int dy = r.nextInt(250) + 250;
    boolean postoji = false;

    public void crtaj(Graphics2D g2d){
        dole = Util.openImage("stub_dole.png");
        gore = Util.openImage("stub_gore.png");
        g2d.drawImage(dole, dx, dy, null);
        g2d.drawImage(gore, dx, -(560-dy), null);
    }

    public void setDx(int dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public void randomDy(){
        this.dy = r.nextInt(250) + 250;
    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dx;
    }
}
```

Ptica/Brid class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



/**
 * Created by Lazar on 26/05/15.
 */

public class Ptica {

    BufferedImage ptica1;
    BufferedImage ptica2;
    boolean ptica;
    boolean skok = false;
    int pad = 0;
    double skokBrojac = 0;

    public Ptica(){
        ptica1 = Util.openImage("/slike/ptica1.png");
        ptica2 = Util.openImage("/slike/ptica2.png");
    }

    public void crtajPticu(Graphics g2d){

        ptica ^= true;

        if(ptica){
            g2d.drawImage(ptica1, Environment.dimension.width/2, Environment.dimension.height/2-110 + pad, null);
        }
        else{
            g2d.drawImage(ptica2, Environment.dimension.width/2, Environment.dimension.height/2-110 + pad, null);
        }

        System.out.println(pad);
    }


    public void setSkok(boolean skok) {
        this.skok = skok;
    }

    public void setSkokBrojac(double skokBrojac) {
        this.skokBrojac = skokBrojac;
    }

    public double getSkokBrojac() {
        return skokBrojac;
    }

    public boolean isSkok() {
        return skok;
    }

    public void setPad(int pad) {
        this.pad = pad;
    }

    public int getPad() {
        return pad;
    }


}
```

Util class:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Lazar on 25/05/15.
 */
public class Util {

    public static BufferedImage openImage(String name){
        try {
            if(!name.startsWith("/slike/")){
                name="/slike/"+name;
            }
            return ImageIO.read(Util.class.getResource(name));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: PaintComponent should paint the current state and nothing else, it should not be making decisions and modifying state

Comment: What does your stub code look like?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I attached the link to the full project but here it is again:[link] http://www.mediafire.com/download/b377ebd17bzzn85/Flappy.rar[/link]

Comment: I dont see a proper game loop/threads used in this code; specially with separation between update and redraw logic so its no wonder it would be slowin a game.

Comment: @Asura The OP is using a Swing Timer as there "game loop"

Comment: @brainiac080195 I'm on an iPad, so the link is not that helpful. You will find most people are reluctant to download anything from people they don't know ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added all the classes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Avoid adding all you classes to the default package, this could cause issues with class loading on some versions of Java
- Painting should paint the state and should not be making decisions or changing the state
- Don't, repeatedly, load resources

For example, from you `Stub` class, which `Environment`'s `paintComponent` calls `crtaj`, you do the following...

```
public void crtaj(Graphics2D g2d){
    dole = Util.openImage("stub_dole.png");
    gore = Util.openImage("stub_gore.png");
    g2d.drawImage(dole, dx, dy, null);
    g2d.drawImage(gore, dx, -(560-dy), null);
}
```

Loading the images can take time.  You should either have a "cache" class which managers them (loading them once) or load them when the `Stub` class is created (I'd prefer the cache class, as if you create and destroy many `Stub`s, loading the resources within the `Stub` class (constructor for example) could become a bottle neck

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184), which was able to go from 200-300 objects moving simultaneously, to over 4000 through the use of a re-usable object cache (rather the re-creating the objects and re-loading their resources)

Comment: It was an easy fix. Loading images in the constructor of the Stub class alone did the trick. I will implement other solutions also :) Thanks man for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler to determine where you code is actually spending time (Note that YourKit has a 15 day free trial license available).

Once you know what your bottleneck is then determine if there's an easy fix, if not consider better algorithms and data-structures to reduce the algorithmic complexity of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling, as suggested by @alex-fitzpatrick, is always good. Also:

- Is the type of images created by your `Util.openImage` call compliant with the graphics2D object you paint on? You may be spending some with the conversions [(image types)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).
- eliminate calls to `getWidth()` etc. You know these values after object initialization, cache them.
- If possible, don't call `repaint` on the entire component. Use the [overloaded version that specifies the area to repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint-long-int-int-int-int-).
- ... and consider using JavaFX for games :-)

Comment: `getWidth` when you need, as size of component might change.  When a component is initialised, the size is unknown until it's laid out, then best time to know that, is when the component is `paintComponent`

Comment: You can add a component listener that will update you only when changes happen: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html

Comment: Yeah, but the cost of calling getWidth/Height as apposed to the event notification overheads would need to be considered, personally, I don't find getWidth/Height that big a drag

Comment: It's not, but it does hurt you when you need the performance most, and that was the issue raised in the question.