# How would I write to a buffer and draw it in Java canvas?

Tags: java, graphics, buffer, rendering

So I am creating a 2D game in Java Swing and awt. I want to use graphics object as least as i can, basically creating an image buffer and writing to it and sending it to the canvas to get rendered. I have limited performance because i am on a raspberry pi, and i am using java and its libraries because most game libraries are not for Raspberry Pi and Java makes it easy for me. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start running off re-inventing the wheel (and probably the whole car), you should by investigating something [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), which provides direct drawing capabilities to a "paged flipping" algorithm.

`BufferStrategy` is limited, as you can't mix it with Swing components, as Swing uses a different rendering approach.

You "could" also use a couple of `BufferedImages`, which act as pages, and manually swap them, which is essentially what `BufferStrategy` does any way, but if you're using Swing, Swing is already double buffered, so you might be just spinning wheels for the want to look cool.

I would "suggest" starting out with something simple and seeing where it takes you, don't try to optimise the solution until you actually start having problems.

Comment: Which method do you recommend?

Comment: @DinamicDigital That depends, how much work do you want to go to?  I'd start with simply using Swing out of the box, while it uses a passive rending engine, it's the simplest place to start, and you can make use of a `BufferedImage` as the primary backing buffer if you wanted to and simply paint it directly onto something like a `JPanel`. If you find that that gives you issues, try looking at using a `BufferStrategy`.

Comment: @DinamicDigital But there is a lot more going on then just the rendering, good resource management is also important - Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184) for some more details