# Creation of new instances of an image slows down animation and creates flickering

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm relatively new to programming in Java. I'm trying to create objects (apples) falling in different locations on the x-axis. However every time a new one is added to the ArrayList the image slows down and flickers

```
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private final int FPS = 60;
    private final int originalSize = 16;
    private final int scale = 3;
    private final int tileSIze = originalSize * scale;
    private final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    private final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    private final int screenWidth = tileSIze * maxScreenCol;
    private final int screenHeight = tileSIze * maxScreenRow;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean start = true;
    private ArrayList<Apple> apples;

    public GamePanel() throws IOException {
        setPanelCharacteristics();
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\IdeaProjects\\AppleCatcher\\src\\apple.png"));
        initApples();
        start();
    }


    public void start() throws IOException {

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double targetTime = 1000000000 / FPS;
                double delta = 0;
                double lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                long currentTime;
                while (start) {
                    currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                    delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / targetTime;
                    lastTime = currentTime;
                    if (delta >= 1) {
                        try {
                            update();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        delta--;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }

    public void initApples() {
        apples = new ArrayList<>();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (start) {
                    try {
                        addApples();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void setPanelCharacteristics() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void addApples() throws IOException {
        Random random = new Random();
        Apple apple = new Apple(screenWidth, screenHeight, image);
        apple.setSize(50, 50);
        int randomX = random.nextInt((screenWidth - apple.getWidth()));
        apple.setLocationX(randomX);
        apples.add(apple);
    }

    public synchronized void update() throws IOException {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            Apple apple = apples.get(i);
            if (apple != null) {
                apple.setVelocity(2);
                apple.animation();
                if (apple.getIsRemoved()) {
                    apples.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics g2D = g.create();
        for (int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            Apple apple = apples.get(i);
            if (apple != null) {
                apple.drawImage(g2D);
            }
        }
        g2D.dispose();
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @author Gebruiker
 */
public class Apple {

    private final BufferedImage apple;
    private final int heightParent;
    private final int widthParent;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int yVelocity = 1;
    private int x;
    private int y = -height;
    private boolean isRemoved = false;

    public Apple(int widthParent, int heightParent, BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        this.heightParent = heightParent;
        this.widthParent = widthParent;
        this.apple = image;

    }

//    public Apple(BufferedImage apple, int heightParent, int widthParent) {
//        this.apple = apple;
//        this.heightParent = heightParent;
//        this.widthParent = widthParent;
//    }

    public void setLocationX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getLocationX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setVelocity(int yVelocity) {
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void drawImage(Graphics g) {
        Graphics g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawImage(apple.getScaledInstance(this.width, this.height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), this.x, this.y, null);
    }

    public boolean getIsRemoved() {
        return isRemoved;
    }

    public synchronized void animation() {
        if (this.y >= this.heightParent) {
//            int randomX = random.nextInt(widthParent - width);
//            this.setLocationX(randomX);
            this.isRemoved = true;
        }
        this.y = this.y + yVelocity;
    }

}
```

I tried to change the way it is rendering but the problem persists. I don't know if there is any better management of the rendering and adding new objects.

Comment: 1) Be careful to correct your code for Swing threading issues. Myself, I'd use a Swing Timer to drive the animation, not a `while (true)` loop. 2) This, `getScaledInstance(...)` is an expensive procedure and will cost you CPU time. Best to scale images only if and when needed, not every time things are rendered. I would scale my image once, if possible, and put the scaled version in a variable and draw it.

Comment: Opinion - I don't see the value of having a seperate generating the apples.  Beware that `ArrayList` is NOT thread safe either. And Swing is also not thread safe, so you "main loop" is of concern.  If you want complete control over the rendering workflow, you'd be better off using a `BufferStrategy`, but, I would investigate your current approach using a Swing `Timer` instead and see if you can make it work, you might just be surprised what you can get away with, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with obvious:

- `ArrayList` is not thread safe, you have multiple threads accessing and update the list which could cause issues.
- Swing is not thread safe. This could cause issues when trying to update the UI, especially when the state the UI relies on is being modified from outside of the Event Dispatching Thread.
- `getScaledInstance(...)` (and even `List#add`) can be expensive calls.  Unless the size of the image is changing dynamically during its life span, scale the image once when the `Apple` is created.
- Repeatedly creating and removing objects can put an overhead on the garbage collection, which can cause slow downs.  If needed, maybe create a pool of entities from which you can draw from, creating them only when needed. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184)

If you absolutely need control over the rendering pipeline, you will need to use `BufferStrategy` instead.

Before you do try that, I recommend trying to make it work within the Swing rendering pipeline, as it will simplify the process.

The following example:

- Decouples the rendering workflow from the state and the update workflow
- Makes use of a Swing `Timer` for the "main loop" which triggers the model to update and schedules the paint pass.
- Adds thread isolation.  This means that the update and paint cycles are done on the same thread.  It also means that adding a new apple is done as part of the update pass.

Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // If the assets fail to load, there's no point
                    // in doing anything else
                    Asset.INSTANCE.prepare();
                    // Decouple the model/state from the UI
                    Model model = new Model();
                    RenderPane renderPane = new RenderPane(model);
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                    frame.add(renderPane);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    renderPane.start();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to load required assets", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class RenderPane extends JPanel {        
        private Timer timer;
        private Model model;

        public RenderPane(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // This now allows the panel to be dynamically
                    // resizable, although if you make the window
                    // smaller, the apples which are now outside
                    // the viewable range will still be updated,
                    // but Swing's pretty well optimised for that
                    model.update(getSize());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            List<Apple> apples = model.getApples();
            for (Apple apple : apples) {
                apple.paint(g2d);
            }
            String text = Integer.toString(apples.size());
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawString(text, getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text) - 8 , getHeight() - fm.getHeight() + fm.getAscent() - 8);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Model {
        private List<Apple> apples;
        private Instant lastAppleUpdate;

        public Model() {
            apples = new ArrayList<>(128);
        }

        public List<Apple> getApples() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(apples);
        }

        public void update(Dimension size) {
            // This will add a new apple approximately every
            // two seconds
            if (lastAppleUpdate == null || Duration.between(lastAppleUpdate, Instant.now()).getSeconds() >= 2) {
                apples.add(new Apple());
                lastAppleUpdate = Instant.now();
            }

            for (int index = apples.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
                Apple apple = apples.get(index);
                apple.update(size);
                if (apple.isRemoved) {
                    apples.remove(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This is just an example, you don't need to do this,
    // but you might consider building some kind of asset
    // management system if you're dealing with multiple
    // assets
    enum Asset {
        INSTANCE;

        private BufferedImage apple;

        private Asset() {
        }

        public void prepare() throws IOException {

            apple = ImageUtilities.getScaledInstanceToFit(
                    ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/apple.png")), 
                    new Dimension(48, 48)
            );
        }

        public BufferedImage getApple() {
            return apple;
        }
    }

    // This demonstrates a "better quality" scaling
    // approach, as apposed to using `getScaledInstance`
    public class ImageUtilities {

        public static BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFit(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {
            float scaleFactor = getScaleFactorToFit(img, size);
            return getScaledInstance(img, scaleFactor);
        }

        protected static float getScaleFactorToFit(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {
            float scale = 1f;
            if (img != null) {
                int imageWidth = img.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = img.getHeight();
                scale = getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(imageWidth, imageHeight), size);
            }
            return scale;
        }

        protected static float getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
            float scale = 1f;
            if (original != null && toFit != null) {
                float dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
                float dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);
                scale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
            }
            return scale;
        }

        protected static float getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {
            float scale = 1;
            if (iMasterSize > iTargetSize) {
                scale = (float) iTargetSize / (float) iMasterSize;
            } else {
                scale = (float) iTargetSize / (float) iMasterSize;
            }
            return scale;
        }

        public static BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor) {
            BufferedImage imgBuffer = null;
            imgBuffer = getScaledInstance(img, dScaleFactor, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, true);
            return imgBuffer;
        }

        protected static BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor, Object hint, boolean higherQuality) {

            int targetWidth = (int) Math.round(img.getWidth() * dScaleFactor);
            int targetHeight = (int) Math.round(img.getHeight() * dScaleFactor);

            int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
                    ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

            BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) img;

            if (targetHeight > 0 || targetWidth > 0) {
                int w, h;
                if (higherQuality) {
                    w = img.getWidth();
                    h = img.getHeight();
                } else {
                    w = targetWidth;
                    h = targetHeight;
                }

                do {
                    if (higherQuality && w > targetWidth) {
                        w /= 2;
                        if (w < targetWidth) {
                            w = targetWidth;
                        }
                    }

                    if (higherQuality && h > targetHeight) {
                        h /= 2;
                        if (h < targetHeight) {
                            h = targetHeight;
                        }
                    }

                    BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(Math.max(w, 1), Math.max(h, 1), type);
                    Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
                    g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
                    g2.dispose();

                    ret = tmp;
                } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
            } else {
                ret = new BufferedImage(1, 1, type);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public class Apple {        
        private static Random RANDOM = new Random();

        private int yVelocity = 1;
        private boolean isRemoved = false;
        private Rectangle bounds;

        public Apple() {
            // If you need the apple to be a different size
            // for each entity, then I would create a copy
            // of the image from the `Assets` here, scale
            // it as desired and assign it a property.
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        public void setVelocity(int yVelocity) {
            this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
            if (bounds == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2D.drawImage(Asset.INSTANCE.getApple(), bounds.x, bounds.y, null);
            g2D.dispose();
        }

        public boolean getIsRemoved() {
            return isRemoved;
        }

        public void update(Dimension size) {
            if (bounds == null) {
                BufferedImage apple = Asset.INSTANCE.getApple();
                this.bounds = new Rectangle(RANDOM.nextInt(size.width - apple.getWidth()), -apple.getHeight(), apple.getWidth(), apple.getHeight());
            }
            if (bounds.getY() >= size.height) {
                this.isRemoved = true;
            }
            bounds.setLocation(bounds.x, bounds.y + yVelocity);
        }

    }
}
```

Just as a side note, I made a mistake when testing the code, which added a new apple on every update pass (so one every 5 milliseconds).  It peaked out at 648 entities without any slow down or issues.